# What is the IntelliJ equivalent to the Eclipse Overview panel?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am switching to IntelliJ from Eclipse and I'm missing the panel provided in the Java perspective of Eclipse that shows the list of all methods for the active class (I believe it is called the Overview panel in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand edge of the IntelliJ window there is a sideways tab named Project and below that a tab named Structure. This is the tab you are looking for! To make it look like the Eclipse default you can drag the tab to the right edge and dock it there.

Note: After hunting around on Stackoverflow and not finding the answer I eventually figured it out on my own. I'm posting my answer here in case other people might benefit.